# Azure Video indexer not retrieve the emotion from video file

Tags: c#, azure, ml.net, face-api, azure-video-indexer

I am trying to retrieve the emotion of peoples in a video file. I am using Azure Video Indexer tool to achieve this. I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/video-indexer-output-json-v2#emotions) about video indexer output file in MSDN website. But my case there is no emotion values are captured in the output json.

[image]

Is there any special input parameter needed to retrieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video Indexer identifies emotions based on speech and audio cues. The identified emotion could be: joy, sadness, anger, or fear.

Here is the piece of code i have written for the same:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VideoIndexer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting process");
            var apiUrl = "https://api.videoindexer.ai";
            var accountId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var location = "trial";
            var apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxx";

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            // create the http client
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);

            // obtain account access token
            var accountAccessTokenRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/auth/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/AccessToken?allowEdit=true").Result;
            var accountAccessToken = accountAccessTokenRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"", "");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key");

            // upload a video
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            Debug.WriteLine("Uploading...");
            // get the video from URL
            //var videoUrl = "https://www.videvo.net/video/young-boy-playing-with-balloons-16/380264/"; // replace with the video URL

            // as an alternative to specifying video URL, you can upload a file.
            // remove the videoUrl parameter from the query string below and add the following lines:
            FileStream video = File.OpenRead(@"C:\MV\LAB\VideoIndexer\1.mp4");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[video.Length];
            video.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(buffer));

            var uploadRequestResult = client.PostAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos?accessToken={accountAccessToken}&name=some_name&description=some_description&privacy=private&partition=some_partition", content).Result;
            var uploadResult = uploadRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            // get the video id from the upload result
            var videoId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(uploadResult)["id"];
            Console.WriteLine("Uploaded");
            Console.WriteLine("Video ID: " + videoId);

            // obtain video access token            
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
            var videoTokenRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/auth/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/AccessToken?allowEdit=true").Result;
            var videoAccessToken = videoTokenRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"", "");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key");

            // wait for the video index to finish
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);

                var videoGetIndexRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/Index?accessToken={videoAccessToken}&language=English").Result;
                var videoGetIndexResult = videoGetIndexRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var processingState = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(videoGetIndexResult)["state"];

                Debug.WriteLine("");
                Debug.WriteLine("State:");
                //Debug.WriteLine(processingState);

                // job is finished
                if (processingState != "Uploaded" && processingState != "Processing")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("Full JSON:");
                    Console.WriteLine(videoGetIndexResult);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // search for the video
            var searchRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/Search?accessToken={accountAccessToken}&id={videoId}").Result;
            var searchResult = searchRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Debug.WriteLine("");
            Debug.WriteLine("Search:");
            Console.WriteLine(searchResult);

            // get insights widget url
            var insightsWidgetRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/InsightsWidget?accessToken={videoAccessToken}&widgetType=Keywords&allowEdit=true").Result;
            var insightsWidgetLink = insightsWidgetRequestResult.Headers.Location;
            Debug.WriteLine("Insights Widget url:");
            Console.WriteLine(insightsWidgetLink);

            // get player widget url
            var playerWidgetRequestResult = client.GetAsync($"{apiUrl}/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos/{videoId}/PlayerWidget?accessToken={videoAccessToken}").Result;
            var playerWidgetLink = playerWidgetRequestResult.Headers.Location;
            Debug.WriteLine("");
            Debug.WriteLine("Player Widget url:");
            Console.WriteLine(playerWidgetLink);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link of the video i have downloaded and feed it into Video indexer

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjyBs6vb0Jk

And here is the JSON output:

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I asked microsoft about this an they said that in cases where the only two emotions identified are positive and negative, the emotions.json file will be empty and instead, the emotions can be found in the "sentiments" object of the index.json file at this endpoint:

`https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Projects/{projectId}/Index[?language][&reTranslate][&accessToken]`

See the `summarizedInsights.sentiments` entry in the json object at:
https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Get-Video-Index

see https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/issues/5ee5037bbe45742290624d0c for MS's full response.